# WSO2 APIM Workflow EI either BPS?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-business-process

I have to deploy the approval workflow as explained in

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Managing+Workflow+Extensions

Currently we are working with 2.1.0, but in the near future, we will migrate to 2.2.0.

In version 2.1.0 to different alternatives are provided: Using EI or using BPS as shown in

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+an+Application+Creation+Workflow

But I see that, in 2.2 version, only the BPS alternative is provided

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Adding+an+Application+Creation+Workflow

As far we understood, EI is the newest, and is a super-set of BPS. Why is the suggestion missed from 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2.2.0 version of APIM works with BPS 3.6 and EI 6.2.0. Yes agree that the 2.2.0 docs should be updated.